# Change detection using Siamese network

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, image-segmentation, siamese-network

I have been trying to find a good way to do a change detection with some images, I have found the following SNUNet paper witht heir github https://github.com/likyoo/Siam-NestedUNet,
but when trying to use it I am always getting a blank output as a segmentation map, what did I do wrong?
here is a link for my colab.
thanks
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1h77eFWXUqTroShuVHueCrejp3F-t9wpm?usp=sharing